Org Chart custom UI edit in LWC not working
I am using Balkan Org chart (Trial version) in LWC. There is a feature to customize the Edit form (https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/Docs/Edit). As per it, the first thing that I have to do is to create javascript class with the following methods:
let editForm = function () {

 };

editForm.prototype.init = function (obj) {

};

editForm.prototype.show = function (node) {

 };

 editForm.prototype.hide = function (showldUpdateTheNode) {

 };

and then instantiate the editForm object as
editUI: new editForm(),

However I have done the following in LWC as per the the ES6 Javascript standards
BalkaChart.js (sample)
        import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
        import orgChartJSF from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/orgchart';

        class editForm{

            constructor() {
            console.log('inside constructir');
            }

            init(obj) {
                console.log('Initializing person:');
            }

            // Method to show data
            show(node) {
                console.log('Showing form data:');
            }

            // Method to show data
            hide(showldUpdateTheNode) {
                console.log('Hiding form data:');
            }

        }


   export default class BalkanOrgchartSample extends LightningElement {

        connectedCallback(){
            // code imported the Org Chart
            this.initiateOrgchart();
        }

        initiateOrgChart(){

             var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
             // mouseScrool: OrgChart.action.none,
             nodeMenu: {
                edit: { text: "Edit" },
                add: { text: "Add" },
                remove: { text: "Remove" }
             },
              editUI: new editForm(),
              nodeBinding: {
                field_0: "name",
                field_1: "title"
              },
              nodes: [
                { id: 1, name: "Amber McKenzie", title: "CEO" },
                { id: 2, pid: 1, name: "Ava Field", title: "IT Manager" },
                { id: 3, pid: 1, name: "Peter Stevens", title: "HR Manager" }
              ]
           });

           }

        }

However the Balkan Org chart failed to load itself afterwards (as long as the editForm class is instantiated).. Anyone stumbled on such a similar issue? Or any idea if I am doing anything wrong? Any suggestions would be helpfull.
